# Are appendices included in the maximum page count for conference papers?

Tags: conference

I am writing research paper following the ACM 2-column format in Latex. The conference is limiting the number of pages by only 6-8 pages. So far, my paper has a lot of figures and tables and would be impossible to fit them all in 8 pages.

So what I want to do, is to include an extra page as an Appendix at the end. will it be considered as 8 pages or 9 pages? Will it be considered that I am following the conference regulation?

Comment: I think this might depend on the conference in question. However, in my rather limited experience with CS conferences, I have only seen a handful of papers with appendices. In all cases, the paper stayed within the 8 page limit, appendix included. So I'd expect your case to be considered as exceeding the limit.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you change the question title to something like "Are appendices included in the maximum page count for conference papers?"

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker okay thanks for your input.

Comment: Ask the conference organizers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are appendices included in the maximum page count for conference publications?

The only way to know for sure is to ask the conference organizers, or look for *instructions for authors* on the website of the conference.

In my experience, the appendix will sometimes **not** be included in the page limit (8 pages + 10 pages of appendix is fine), but the appendix will not be published in the conference proceedings (if any). It will thus only be used during the review process. Therefore, you would want to fit important figures/tables in the main text, not in the appendix.

Comment: It will only be used during the review process, *at the discretion of the reviewers*. The reviewers are often free to ignore the additional material.

Answer (score 3):

> Are appendices included in the maximum page count for conference publications?

In my experience from CS, typically yes. That is because the page limit has (at least) three purposes:

- To ensure everyone gets the same space to make their point (whether that increases fairness or actually decreases it - different topics may require different amounts of space - is a different question).
- To limit the amount of information/contributions per publication, lest the conference talk be just an exemplary excerpt that fails to encompass the entirety of the paper.
- **To actually limit page size in printed proceedings.** I base this on the observation that I have come across conferences that would charge authors for extra pages, and even a few that would charge authors or put a (lower-than-total-pages) limit on pages with coloured content.

It is for the latter point that "bonus material" such as appendices also counts towards the maximum paper length.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it depends; make sure to check the submission guidelines.

For example, from the top two database conferences, [SIGMOD 2017](http://sigmod2017.org/sigmod-call-for-research-papers/) research papers have the requirement "12 pages + 4 pages for bibliography/appendix", while [VLDB 2017](http://www.vldb.org/2017/submission_guidelines.php) states, "The maximum research paper length, inclusive of ALL material, is 12 pages. "

And, as you can see from the other answers, even within CS conferences, practices vary wildly. So, the only way to really know is to find the instructions for the conference you are targeting. If you cannot find specific instructions regarding an appendix, and cannot contact the organizers, you should probably assume that the page limit stated is strict and includes anything you might include in the paper, including appendices and references.